# Expression syntax with if command using curly braces in csh

Tags: bash, syntax, csh

I'm trying to check if a volume is mounted using a csh script.

This code works

```
#!/bin/csh
set MOUNT_FOLDER = "/Volumes/AAA"
if ( `mount | grep -c "on $MOUNT_FOLDER"` == 0 ) then
    echo Not mounted
else
    echo Mounted
endif
```

but I would like to try using the syntax with { } and the exit code of `grep`. I've tried with

```
if ( { mount | grep -q "on $MOUNT_FOLDER" } ) then
...
```

but it prints the `mount` output and it regardless the value of `$MOUNT_FOLDER` the expression is always `true`.

Comment: `csh` or `bash`?

Comment: I'm interested in the csh. I've got a working version of using bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in `bash`, if You have piped commands in `csh` and want get command exit status You need to encapsulate in sub-shell `( ... | ... )`

So following should work for You:

```
if ( { ( mount | grep -q "on $MOUNT_FOLDER" ) } ) then
...
```

Comment: The syntax is fine. The only thing I have to change is to put ! at the beginning `if ( ! { ( mount | grep -q "on $MOUNT_FOLDER" ) } ) then`. Thanks